# Character inferno

Tags: java, character-encoding, cp1252

I need some help. I have to read data from a file and store it into an Oracle db. I run into troubles when characters like 'à' or 'À' appear into data. For example, 'à' is read and become 'Ã ' into my application, so, when I try to save data into db, sometimes, the db complains about values too big about the field that are going to save into. I also tryied

`Normalizer.normalize(row, Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");`

I payed attention about encoding too. I notice that if I run my application on data file, a Cp1252 file, on a Windows machine I got no errors. Sadly I got errors when I run the stuff on a Linux machine. I'm using java 6. TIA.

Comment: When reading the file, you need to convert from bytes to string with the appropriate character set. You seem to be using the default charset.

Comment: Hello @assylias, I read the file by this instruction: `br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.txt")), Charset.forName("Cp1252")));`
I change the Charset value to UTF-8 when the file is on a linux machine.

Comment: Don't change that line on the linux machine! The file is encoded with the cp1252 charset, so even on linux, you need to read it with that charset (unless I've missed something).

Comment: In other words, if the file is encoded in cp1252 and is on a Windows machine, to read it from a linux machine, you need to use: `br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.txt")), Charset.forName("Cp1252")));`

Comment: @assylias you are right and that's the way I'm reading data. The problem persist. I tried to catch char using this code: 
`row = Normalizer.normalize(row, Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
 Iterator<Integer> iterator = charmap.keySet().iterator();
 Integer cursor;
 while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     cursor = iterator.next();
     row.replace(new String(Character.toChars(cursor)), new String(Character.toChars(charmap.get(cursor))));
 }
 return row;`
where `row` is a `String`, `charmap` is a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` containing unicode codepoint values. No success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the default character encoding on your windows machine is probably windows-1252 (a superset of latin-1).  That means that if you don't specify the charset when reading in the file, Java will default to your system default and get it right.

On your Linux machine, your default charset is probably UTF-8.  That means that if you don't not explicitly specify a charset while reading a file, it will default to UTF-8 . . . which, in this case, is wrong.

You didn't post how you're reading in your file, but for example:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(file, "UTF-8");
```

This would create an input stream reader for reading a file formatted in UTF-8.

Comment: Hello. Thankyou for replying. I read data from a windows file on a linux machine. Here is how i read it: `br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.txt")), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`

Comment: Well there's your problem right there.  You're reading a windows-1252 file as UTF-8.  Use "Cp1252" instead.